# Summarize Null Values in Table with Group By

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I have two tables:

- Person(ID, Name)
- Sports(person_ID, Sport)

The Problem: Sport can have NULL values. And if that is the case then if I group by ID the sport should be NULL.

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Name, s.Sport
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN Sports s ON p.ID=s.person_id
GROUP BY p.ID
```

Without the Group By the table looks like this:

```
p.ID p.Name s.Sport
1    tom    soccer
1    tom    NULL
2    lisa   golf
2    lisa   soccer
3    tim    golf
3    tim    NULL
```

What I want now:

```
1 tom NULL
2 lisa golf
3 tim NULL
```

But what I get:

```
1 tom soccer
2 lisa golf
3 tim golf
```

I've tried subselects and ifs but I couldn't get anything to work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why should Lisa play golf and not soccer?

Comment: If i run this the Group by function always picks the first row if there are multiple (on my system). But that doesnt matter really. I only need tim and tom to be NULL

Comment: Use case expression in the select list to do conditional aggregation. Remember that count(*) <> count(column) if the column has null values.

Comment: @stuckonhere why don't you just add `where sport is NULL ` to the query?

Comment: If I only add IS NULL it removes the lisa entry and i need this entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query which should generate your expected result set, though as @jarlh has pointed out, it isn't clear why Lisa should play golf over soccer.

```
SELECT
    p.ID,
    p.Name,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN s.Sport IS NULL THEN 1 END) > 0
         THEN NULL ELSE MIN(s.Sport) END AS Sport
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN Sports s
    ON p.ID = s.person_id
GROUP BY
    p.ID,
    p.name;
```

Note that I group by both the `ID` and `name`, which would be required on many databases (though perhaps not SQLite).

Comment: This works! That is quite the useful expression Count(Case...). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can't manage the NULL value with aggreagtion function as MIN() 
but you could try

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Name, min(ifnull(s.Sport,'')) 
FROM Person p 
INNER JOIN Sports s ON p.ID=s.person_id 
GROUP BY p.ID, p.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the version of SQLLite you are using supports `row_number()`, please try below, you can set a `row_number` to 1 if you `order by s.sport ASC`, then select the first row for each category. If there is NULL, it should locate at the top row of each category via this query. You don't need to use `group by`:

```
;with cte as (
select p.ID, p.Name, s.Sport, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.ID ORDER BY s.Sport ASC) AS rn
FROM Person p INNER JOIN Sports s ON p.ID=s.person_id
)
select *
from cte
where rn=1
```

Comment: This of course assumes that the OP's version of SQLite supports `ROW_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a correlated subquery, avoiding the `join` in the outer query:

```
select p.*,
       (select s.sport
        from sports s
        where s.personId = p.id
        order by (s.sport is null) desc, s.sport asc
       ) as min_sport
from person p;
```

This may prove useful under some circumstances.  With an index on `sports(personid, sport)`, it *might* be faster than the `group by`, depending on the data (lots of people, few sports per person).

Also, this is slightly different from your query because it returns all people, even those with no sports.